# MvvmCross Device Default ActionBar Color on MvxFragmentActivity

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to migrate from MvxTabActivity to the new ViewPager.  The problem is that when you do this, you no longer have a default ActionBar and have to define one in your layout.  Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            local:tabGravity="center"
            local:tabMode="scrollable" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "PayItemView", Theme = "@style/MPSTheme")]

public class PayItemView : MvxFragmentActivity
{
    PayItemViewModel vm;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar myToolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        myToolbar.Title = "Current Pay Summary - " + Common.Settings.DriverName;

    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet();

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PayItemView);

        vm = (this.DataContext as PayItemViewModel) ?? null;

        var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null)
        {
            var fragments = new List<MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>
            {
                new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("OTR", typeof (OTRTabView),
                    typeof (OTRTabViewModel)),
                new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("LPP", typeof (LPPTabView),
                    typeof (LPPTabViewModel)),
                new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("Hours", typeof (HourTabView),
                    typeof (HourTabViewModel)),
            };
            viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(this, SupportFragmentManager, fragments);
        }

        var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

I created my style as follows:

```
<style name="MPSTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3f51b5</item>
</style>
```

I added a random color to the colorPrimary attribute of the Style and it works.  The problem is that the rest of my App uses the device default color for the ActionBar.  If you don't use a Theme based on Theme.AppCompat, it won't inflate your view.  Is there a way to make my Theme be based on Theme.AppCompat and use the colorPrimary from the Device Default Theme?

Comment: Do you want to use your own color or use device default? :) Not entirely clear

Comment: I want the device default color.  I figure that I need to determine what it is and set it as the value for colorPrimary.

Comment: You should make a theme, instead of relying on Android to pick one for you. The different versions of Android may have completely different default themes, and could mess up your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in an `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            local:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

Comment: That still uses the AppCompat theme and that is where the problem is.  The rest of my App uses the default theme.

Comment: Having just read your comments with Stupidus. You should definitely make a theme and use that throughout your app.